# Is there a Rust crate that auto-box large enum variant?

Tags: memory, rust, enums

Recently clippy warned me [result_large_err](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#result_large_err) a few times. I remember I encountered a crate on [crates.io](https://crates.io/), probably a proc_macro, that while derived on an enum, will automatically box enum variant if considered large enough.

Something like

```
#[derive(AutoBoxLargeVariant)]
pub enum ParseError {
    UnparsedBytes([u8; 512]),
    UnexpectedEof,
}
```

will be translated to

```
pub enum ParseError {
    UnparsedBytes(Box<[u8; 512]>),
    UnexpectedEof,
}
```

I think it may be an elegant solution for the result_large_err issue, but failed to recall its name. After some search, the only thing I found relevant was [smallbox](https://crates.io/crates/smallbox), which does not quite match my memory.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, but what's wrong with simply running `clippy` and boxing the offending variants manually? In fact, this proc-macro might be in general impossible - it has only tokens, not types, so it will fail if, e.g., the `[u8; 512]` is wrapped in a struct.

Comment: This is very bad idea. You shouldn't hide such important details away. Rust is all about being explicit. Besides, it's not something inherent bad. That's why it's a lint. When you get warned then you should think and make a conscious  decision how you want to approach it in this instance.

Comment: Running clippy and boxing manually is ok but feels boring. I don't know how it is implemented (if it do exist), perhaps a build script or something more complicated, I just glimpsed its introduction. It feels very intriguing to try it out, compared to mannually boxing. Maybe it will turn out only to be my memory corruption

Comment: Maybe instead of using a macro you should learn how to use your code editor to refactor your code more quickly, including a bunch of `Box<...>` and `Box::.new(...)` where they are needed.